# Did Swami Vivekananda ever write a book called Gnana deepam?

Tags: vivekananda

So, I found these suspicious pictures in twitter.

[image: Completely different from what I read.]

> Christian preachers and missionaries are badly needed for India. Let them come here in hundreds and thousands. Teach us about the Holy life and history of JESUS. Let His spiritual teachings penetrate the heart of our society. Preach in every nook and corner about JESUS CHRIST…. (Swami Vivekananda Part 1, page 128-129 Gnana Deepam)

[image: ...]

> If you want Mukthi (Salvation) follow JESUS.....is in the top most priority than any other GOD you can imagine ("Gnana Deepam", part-7, page 294)

After searching web I found some old dead links to a tamil book Gnana deepam by vivekananda (not sure if this is **the** Swami Vivekananda), published in 1963. Unfortunately, I cannot find copy of this book.

Can someone verify the legitimacy of these quotes?

Comment: **Swami Vivekananda Actually criticized Christian missionaries** for ignoring the needs of starving millions in India. He further stated in Chicago that " He said that the **people did not need missionaries** to preach to them or to build more churches; there was already a surfeit of religion in the East. Thousands had perished out of hunger but the Christians had ignored them" See [Religion not the crying need of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_not_the_crying_need_of_India) .So the quotes look dubious at first glance

Comment: Looks like a bogus work attributed to him. Could not find it in wiki. Amazon India has it in Tamil, but currently no copies are available.

Comment: no, he didn't. I have read his Complete Works and never found any such thing.

Comment: bogus. Vivekananda was highly critical of the Christian missionaries. There is no book that he wrote that you refer to. If you refer to Vol 3 of his Complete Works, Lectures from Colombo to Almora, he, in fact, says that only the through the Santana Dharma can moksha be achieved.

Comment: OK, these pictures are fake. Thanks everyone for commenting.

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/Swami-Vivekanandarin-Gnana-Deepam-volumes/dp/B077YGD84H copy of the book, just found this

Answer (score -3):

Brother, the words in this pictures are not at all fake , all are original,  even twenty years back I was searched this book to clarify the same doubt,  but book was not available in the market,  that printing was stopped because so many people  can be accepted Jesus as a god,  so some religious leader got the rights of the book and stopped the book

But original copy of old printing was available in some old library and in some Ministry hands

You just think about it
If it is not a original quote from that book itself
Religious people will go to court and file a case against them surely,  but why it was not happening till now ( past 50 years)
So try to find out a original copy of this book,  and if this book was not available in the market,  just ask a question for you,  why this book was blocked,  then you find a reality
(Swami Vivekananda Part 1, page 128-129 Gnana Deepam)